# Срабатывает else(по идее не должно)

Tags: python-3.6

Должно сработать if, но почему то происходит обратное. Хотя условия вроде верны. Короче, взгляните сами:

```
list = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]

def check():
                                  
    a = input("Введите число: ")
                                 
    if a[-1:] in list: print("Это число не чётное!")
                              
    else: print("Это число чётное!")

check()
```

Comment: Что такое по твоему  a[-1:]?

Comment: Это вы не знаете или что-то тут не то?

Comment: Ну это последняя цифра числа, которую ввёл пользователь.

Comment: Цифра ли? Числа ли? А почему же для числа используется срез, который для числа в принципе невозможно применить?

Comment: Подсказка: "5" и 5 - совсем не одно и то же.

Comment: Ну input же принимает как string) Так что можно.

Comment: Что можно-то? Ещё раз: "5" не равно 5

Comment: Повторюсь ещё раз, input принимает данные в string, это не integer.

Comment: Если я что-то не до понимаю, пожалуйста объясните, я для этого сюда и пришёл.

Comment: Я могу ещё раз повторить, что "5" не равно 5. И результат if "5" == 5 (это именно то, что происходит в коде) всегда будет False. Строка никогда не будет равна числу. В списке - числа. Сравнение производится со строкой.

Comment: Я понял что вы говорите, ну так я вам и говорю что введённое число является string, а не integer

Comment: Хотя подождите...

Comment: Боже!!! Извините пожалуйста!

Comment: До меня только допёрло!

Comment: Все нормально. Все на этом попадались :)

Comment: Так и сказали бы что проблема в списке)

Comment: Нет, проблема не в списке. Можно или в список внести строки или же введённое "число" конвертировать в число. Но обычно четность проверяют остатком от деления на 2.

Comment: Да знаю, но было задание сделать проверку без деления)

Comment: В любом случае спасибо!